Read and Write Into HUGE json files
I am working on Mongo ChangeStreams and storing my db changes (before and after) packets in my local system and then another script reads and upload these files to s3.
My Folder structure:
Parent_Folder -> Accounts -> 2024-05-23.json
Now, some of these json files are going up to 500Mb in size which makes reading and writing it very difficult as it loads the file into the memory. Also, JSON sometimes giving Error: Too long to parse
The code I'm currently using:
async function exportToLocalFile(data, collectionName) { // THIS FUNCTION IS BEING CALLED FOR EVERY CHANGE DETECTED IN DB (frequency is VERY high)
  const currentDate = new Date()
  const year = currentDate.getFullYear()
  const month = (currentDate.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
  const day = currentDate.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
  const filePath = `${LOCAL_AUDIT_LOGS_STORAGE_FOLDER}/${collectionName}/${year}-${month}-${day}.json`

  checkAndDeleteDayOlderFiles(collectionName)

  // READING DATA HERE:: Append data if file exists already
  const existingData = readJSONFile(filePath) || []
  console.log({ existingData })

  let finalObject = [data, ...existingData]

  console.log({ finalObject })

  // Write updated JSON back to file
  fs.writeFileSync(filePath, JSON.stringify(finalObject, null, 2), 'utf-8')

  console.log('Data written to file successfully. ' + filePath)
}

function readJSONFile(filePath) {
  try {
    const fileExists = fs.existsSync(filePath)
    if (fileExists) {
      const data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, 'utf8')
      return JSON.parse(data)
    } else {
      return null
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error reading file:', error)
    return null
  }
}


/// UPLOADING on s3 :::

async function readAndExportToS3(directory) {
  let files = fs.readdirSync(directory)

  for (let file of files) {
   
    const filePath = path.join(directory, file)
    console.log({ filePath })

    // Check if the file is a directory
    if (fs.statSync(filePath).isDirectory()) {
      console.log('Its a directory!')
      await readAndExportToS3(path.join(directory, file))
    } else {
      console.log("Its a file, let's upload!")
      const key = path.join(directory, file).replace(/\\/g, '/')
      const finalKey = key.split('db_audit_logs/')[1]
      let fileContent = fs.readFileSync(filePath).toString()

      // Upload the file to S3
      const uploadParams = {
        Bucket,
        Key: finalKey,
        Body: fileContent,
        ContentType: 'application/json',
      }

      try {
        let data = await s3.upload(uploadParams).promise()
        console.log('Uploaded sucessfully :: ', data.Location)
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Error uploading ', file, { err })
      }


    }
  }
}


Just want to know is there a better, faster, and efficient way of reading/writing/parsing such JSON files. Any nudge in the right direction will surely help. Open to any suggestions.

(1) Add more memory to the box running this, or (2) since you apparently know the only edit you'd need to be doing to the file is prepending new data, do that with string manipulation. (3) For the upload, don't read the file into memory – surely s3.upload() has a mode where it can deal with a stream.

Actually the problem is more with the READing and appending part as the process either takes too much memory or stops with errors, upload part - I can check later (with s3 functions) @AKX

You might look for a streaming json library. They can be a little harder to work with (it can require a different paradigm) but they have a much smaller memory footprint. Also you might consider a different storage format.

I don't know where people got the idea that JSON made a good database.  JSON was just supposed to be for communication.  If you need a database, then for gosh sakes use a database.  What you're doing here is silly.

Oh, and if you're working with MongoDB change streams where each change is a JSON document, use JSONL to store them (in the absence of a database).

As a lot of people said, json is very ram hungry as it require you to load the entire data in the ram before using it, and should be only used for data transfer, not storage.
My best bet would be to use a simple reader that can read line by line a file and according to, for example, a first character or word, it can return the entire line.
Or, the simplest way to deal dynamicly with huge data is just using any kind of database, but the simplest one is sqlite3 as it allow you to use a single file as a database, and it of course doesn't load the entire data in memory.

fun fact, because I didn't know this before, I had a program that required 4 Peta bytes of ram . Bluescreened everytime my computer

JSON itself doesn't require you to load the entire data into RAM; there are libraries that can read JSON in an eventful way. JSON.parse() isn't one of those.
